# Как сделать запрет на растягивание формы в C++buider

Tags: c++builder, форма

Собственно я сделал `Page Control` на форму, но мне нужно что бы не было растягивания формы 
см фото

[image: img]

Comment: Поставьте у формы свойство `BorderStyle` в `bsSingle`.

Comment: да не что то не то , я на форму наложил  Page Control

Comment: Продолжим гадать... PageControl'у Align поставить alClient.